# accepts_nested_attributes_for with complex association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using accepts_nested_attributes_for in one of my Rails app. i have three models :album has_many :photo and each :photo has_and_belongs_to_many :tag. User can add more photo in album using paperclip and jquery.multifile.js. every thing working fine but the main problem is the hash is not properly create.

```
album => {:name => "", :body => "", :photos_attributes => {"tags_attributes" => {:name => "abc"}, "photo" => {"file" => "tempfile"}}}
```

but i need.

```
album => {:name => "", :body => "", :photos_attributes => "photo" => {"file" => "tempfile", "tags_attributes" => {:name => "abc"}}}}
```

My view is: please consider the gallery => album and attachment => photo

```
<%= form_for(@gallery, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <div id = "gallery_name_formField">
        <%= f.label "Gallery Name:" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name, :name => "gallery[name]" %><br />
    </div>
    <div id = "gallery_body_formField">
        <%= f.label "Gallery Description:" %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :body, :name => "gallery[body]" %><br />
    </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |af| %>
        <div id = "gallery_file_formField">
            <%= af.label "Select The Attachment:" %><br />
            <%= af.file_field(:attachment, :name => "gallery[attachments_attributes][][attachment]")%>
        </div>
        <div id="tags">
            <%= af.fields_for :tags do |tf| %>
                <%= tf.label :name, "Tag:" %><br />
                <%= tf.text_field :name, :id => "mySingleField_0", :name => "gallery[attachments_attributes][][tags_attributes][][name]" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="attachment_submit_formField">
        <%= f.submit(:id => "create_gallery") %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think the format of the hash is decided by your fields_for parameters. Can you share your view code in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use nested form gem? [Give it a try](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/)

Its very straightforward way to have multiple nested forms.

It works for me.